# Как вычесть из результата одного запроса COUNT результат второго аналогичного запроса?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица, в которую записываются резервы: имя, дата, тип места и его статус (занято/свободно).
Я хочу высчитывать сколько есть доступных мест на определенный день: из общего списка мест, которые доступны всегда

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `personal_reserv` WHERE type='two';
```

вычитаю количество мест, которые заняты в искомый день.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM personal_reserv WHERE dates='19.06.22' AND busy='yes';
```

Не могу понять, как объединить два запроса в один. Из кода посылать два разных запроса и считать их разницу - выглядит таким себе решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно как-то так?

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) - (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM personal_reserv 
    WHERE dates='19.06.22' AND busy='yes' 
)) as count 
FROM `personal_reserv` 
WHERE type='two';
```

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит логичным, но phpMyAdmin пишет, что неизвестный оператор рядом со вторым as. Пробовал менять запрос, но не подходит. Скорей всего я в чем-то туплю, но не могу в чем, гугл тоже не помогает

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка была из-за `;` рядом с `busy='yes'`. Надо убрать.

Comment: И то верно. Спасибо большое за помощь!